# Are this if statements equal?

Tags: php, if-statement

i came across a php statement and was thinking, is

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])==1){

}
```

very similar to

```
if (isset($_SESSION['id']) && $_SESSION['id']==1){

}
```

Comment: And your question is ... ?

Comment: You have, `var_dump();` the gratest to debug php, use it with `die;` step by step to see, what the things are returning, and you will be able to figure out yourself

Comment: isset() returns TRUE if var exists and has value other than NULL, `isset( $_SESSION['id'] ) == 1` will always be TRUE if $_SESSION['id'] exists and has value different than NULL.

Comment: what makes you think they are equal. Even if you look at the codes clearly they are not equal,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us break it down.

```
isset($_SESSION['id']) == 1
```

The first part, the `isset()` call, will return a boolean value (`true` or `false`), depending on if the session id is set or not.

When you compare an integer value with a boolean value, using the `==` operator, the integer will be coerced (or *cast*/*type-juggled*) into a boolean value. So, if the integer is a "truthy" value, i.e. greater than or equal to 1, then it will be turned into `true`. If it is lower than or equal to 0 then it will be turned into `false`.

In other words, if the session is set then the expression will be turned into `true === true` (which evaluates to `true`). If it is not set then it will be turned into `false === true` (which evaluates to `false`).

So, in conclusion, it probably does not do what you thought it did. Use the latter if statement.

Comment: Actually according to [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), when you compare a boolean value (on the left) with an integer using `==`, the integer value is coerced to a boolean, not the other way around. You can test this by comparing `true` with 2 (or any other non-zero value) instead of 1. They will still compare as equal because all non-zero integer values convert to `true`..

Comment: @TedHopp You are right. I got it the wrong way round. Fixed it. Thank you for catching it :)

Answer (score 2):

The statements are not equivalent. Because `isset()` returns either `TRUE` or `FALSE`, the first test:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])==1){

}
```

is exactly equivalent to:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){

}
```

because php converts `1` to the Boolean value `TRUE` so the `==` operator has compatible types. The second, on the other hand, not only test whether `$_SESSION['id']` is set, but also, if it is, whether the value is set to `1` (after type juggling to resolve comparing a string with an integer).